# Configure request timeout for WebApi controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using async methods in my WebAPi controllers:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SampleMethod(int subscriptionNumber, DateTime departureDate)
{
    // [...]
}
```

How do I configure the request timeout? The operation can take up to a couple of minutes and I have to make sure that the request do not timeout.

In MVC there is an attribute called `[AsyncTimeout]`. Are there an equivalent in WebApi? Can it be configured globally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question, I would recommend to handle this from client side - you can always specify timeout settings in your consumer code, even if it is ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
timeout: 1000,
...
```

Comment: Are you saying that IIS/ASP.NET/WebApi2 do not have any built in timeouts?

Comment: Yes, they don't have anything so far. WebAPI support cancellation tokens to cancel the operation, so that you can try to use CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter to achieve that, but as I mentioned - from consuming code

Comment: Also the following excerpt reveals a bit more why: "The way to cancel HTTP requests is to cancel them on the HttpClient directly. The reason being that multiple requests can reuse TCP connections within a single HttpClient and so you can't safely cancel a single request without possibly affecting other requests as well."