# Web API user account registration is timing out in azure

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have created a web api, with asp.net "Inidividual User Accounts" authentication. It is working fine on my local host and I am able register with the registration endpoint.

http://localhost/api/Account/Register

But the same web-api when deployed to azure(as cloud service) is timing out, and I get the below response.

> Abort / timeout
>
> The request has been aborted manually or because of the connection
>   timeout. There were no response from the server but the connection
>   wasn't closed.
>
> You can adjust timeout in settings.
>
> Try to:
>
> add "Connection: close" header which should be used by the server to
>   close the connection after it finish generating response

What could be the issue, and how can I increase the timeout.

Comment: if not already do check these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403832/timeout-a-web-api-request  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630984/configure-request-timeout-for-webapi-controllers

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out myself. I had to increase the timeout in the web.config as  below

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue occuring while using ARC (Advanced Rest Client) Chrome plugin. The answer for me was to toggle on the 'Use XHR' button on. see https://marcustalcott.com/2016/11/03/error-making-a-rest-call/?iframe=true&theme_preview=true